# cordova reading file fails with not found error

Tags: javascript, android, file, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm using media capture plugin to record voices and take pictures on android.

while I can play recorded voice easily with `Media.fullPath` and media plugin, I cant access captured image by `Media.fullPath` Or `Media.localURL`.

I have file plugin installed and tried `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` and `image.src` with both `file` and `cdvfile` formats and get not found error.
Media.fullPath returns like:

`file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1536249436147.jpg`

and Media.localURL returns like:

`cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Pictures/1536250346937.jpg`

both of them cause error code 1 in `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` and not found in image.src.